# Placeholder text-align

Tags: html, css

I am using the following style for placeholder, but it turns the input text (when i start typing) to start from right to left. Now i am seeing this [example](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/styling-placeholder-text-input-fields-forms-css/), it is just text-align, but why mine is formatting wrong? Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1zuo69q/) for my example

```
input[placeholder="Required"]{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector `input[placeholder="Required"]` selects an input with a placeholder attribute, not the placeholder itself.

Use the selectors given in your example:

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}
input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}
input::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="blocks">
    <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="name" placeholder="Required">
  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <label for="Email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="Email" id="Email" name="email" placeholder="Required">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what is the difference between `input::-webkit-input-placeholder` and `input[placeholder="Required"]`

Comment: As I explained in my answer: The first one selects the placeholder text and the second one selects the input element

Comment: so what will be the syntax if i do it without different browsers syntax, a simple selection for input element?

Comment: For placeholder? It's just `::placeholder`

Answer (score 1):

Because in the example it styles the placeholder and not the input element (*like you do*).

```
input[placeholder="Required"]::-moz-placeholder{ text-align: right; }
input[placeholder="Required"]::-ms-input-placeholder{ text-align: right; }
input[placeholder="Required"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ text-align: right; }
```

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/z1zuo69q/2/