# What on earth is causing this input placeholder text to not text-align to anything but center?

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder, text-align

So I've been fighting with this for maybe a week off and on and every time I end up eventually giving up. There's a "search bar" input at the top right of this website I'm working on [here](https://store.melrosemac.com/). There's lots of information on text-aligning the placeholder text for inputs like this right [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250863/placeholder-text-align) and I've built out lots of these without ever having an issue with this. But for some reason on this site, I can't just apply something like 'text-align: left;', the text remains centered. I know this is a dumb question but I'm really confused on what's causing this. I can't seem to recreate this in a CodePen at all, it always behaves as expected everywhere except for on this production site.

Does anyone know why this specific input seems to not respond to "text-align: left;"? I'm using Chrome but every browser I've tested displays this the same way - centered placeholder text no matter what I do. I think I'm missing something simple here but I don't have a clue what it is.

Comment: Maybe right click, go to web inspector and examine the CSS hierarchy on that element to find what is overriding your rules

Comment: ... It's not clear or I wouldn't be here asking. You clearly don't know either.

Answer (score 2):

That is not text. That is placeholder.

please add below to css

```
input.form-control.search::placeholder {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: white-space: nowrap fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into the code and I honestly have no idea what is causing this but I have a solution :)

```
<style>
   .search::-webkit-input-placeholder{
      text-align: left !important;
   }
</style>
```

Set the important tag to tell the browser that that thingie maginie is important and set the property to the placeholder of the '.search'

Answer (score 1):

Probably, he know what is a placeholder. The problem is `text-align: center` from your placeholder. If you want to see it with developer tools:

> The trick is to enable 'Show user agent shadow DOM' in the Settings
> panel of Chrome Developer Tools. Thank to Sean Anderson for [the
> answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853319/15924734)

Also you can edit your placeholder using [vendor-prefixed selectors](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/)

Comment: Super helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the style.css file:

```
  .header-main .search-wrapper .search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     text-align: center;
    }
```

It's got quite a high specificity so worth copying the lot and simply doing:

```
  .header-main .search-wrapper .search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     text-align: left;
    }
```